# Adaptive Huffman encoding and decoding at different time

Tags: algorithm, compression

Adaptive Huffman is used for real time compression and decompression. My question is can we use it where we want to encode in real time,save all the encoded data and decode later any other time? Because I found that the Huffman tree keep changing for each new character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You replicate the building of the Huffman tree on the decoding side.  So long as the process of updating the tree depends only on previous data, then it can be replicated exactly on the other end using the decoded data so far.

Answer (score 0):

With Adaptive encoding, the code dictionary doesn't need to be sent upfront, because it's dynamically reconstructed as the data is sent.

For example, consider the following string to be compressed `AAB` (assuming symbol length 1). The tree will be dynamically constructed as the string is read by either the compressor or the decompressor:

[image: Adaptive Huffmann Encoding]

Note that DAG here refers to the 0-node that's output whenever a new symbol is found and its frequency is always considered zero.

The final code (already containing the symbols themselves) is:

```
0 01000001 0 1 01000010
```

Note that `01000001` is the 8-bit ASCII code of `A`, while `01000010` is the 8-bit ASCII code for `B`.

Play around with it yourself at this [Adaptive Huffman Encoding](http://miscalculators.com/adaptive-huffman-encoding/)